# Optimize count matrix algorithm for chars in list of words

Tags: r

I have a feature to create a count matrix for chars in a given vector of words and then plot it into a neat visual based on the position, weighted by count. However, the run-time is brutally slow for larger sets, mainly because I have a fairly beginner algo running with O(n^2) due to nested loops.

As the words get larger, it becomes an expensive computation causing a bottleneck at this feature. I'm still a novice with R, **but could anyone suggest an optimization anywhere in the algo or point me to a vectorized function already optimized for something like this**? I'm trying to stay in base R for minimizing dependencies but not super critical.

For sake of reprex, here's a small sample of words at (length(word) == 5):

```
mtx <- matrix(0, byrow=TRUE, nrow=26, ncol=5)
rownames(mtx) <- letters
colnames(mtx) <- c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05")
word_set <- c("clear", "laugh", "cigar", "honda", "tulip", "asset")

for (word in 1:length(word_set)) {

  for (letter in 1:nchar(word_set[word])) {

    chars_in_word <- strsplit(word_set[word], "")[[1]] # Split word into chars
    letter_position <- colnames(mtx)[letter] # Define rowname as letter_position
    letter_match <- rownames(mtx)[match(chars_in_word[letter], rownames(mtx))] # Find which row the char is equal to
    mtx[letter_match, letter_position] <- mtx[letter_match, letter_position] + 1.0000 # Increment tally

  }
}
```

My approach is to

1. Split each word into individual chars
2. Match the char to one of the rows (labeled a:z) and then
3. Increment by 1 at the matched position (colnames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the string on every character, `unlist` and put in a matrix and count the number of times a letter occurred at a particular position.

```
apply(matrix(unlist(strsplit(word_set, "")), nrow = length(word_set), 
      byrow = TRUE), 2, function(x) table(factor(x, levels = letters)))


#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#a    1    1    0    2    1
#b    0    0    0    0    0
#c    2    0    0    0    0
#d    0    0    0    1    0
#e    0    0    1    1    0
#f    0    0    0    0    0
#g    0    0    1    1    0
#h    1    0    0    0    1
#i    0    1    0    1    0
#j    0    0    0    0    0
#k    0    0    0    0    0
#l    1    1    1    0    0
#m    0    0    0    0    0
#n    0    0    1    0    0
#o    0    1    0    0    0
#p    0    0    0    0    1
#q    0    0    0    0    0
#r    0    0    0    0    2
#s    0    1    1    0    0
#t    1    0    0    0    1
#u    0    1    1    0    0
#v    0    0    0    0    0
#w    0    0    0    0    0
#x    0    0    0    0    0
#y    0    0    0    0    0
#z    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: @akrun and RonakShah thanks for the help. I should have specified better that I'm trying to have the colnames (rownames in your case akrun) as the **character-position** in the word, rather than the word position in the character-vector. Doing it the way you both offered results in tables that have thousands of rows/cols (since the list I have is much larger). So that's why for the word vector I provided, the colnames in the table were 01:05 (for each character in the word). 

Is there an easy correction? I'll play with both of these answers though and see how they work.

Comment: @mfnight I see. I misunderstood the question earlier. Please have a look at updated answer.

Comment: I think this can be simplified to only call a `table` operation once on a long list of letters with corresponding position - `spl <- strsplit(word_set, ""); table(data.frame(let=factor(unlist(spl),levels=letters), pos=sequence(lengths(spl))))`

Comment: Thanks! The update worked perfect. And thanks for the addition @thelatemail. Both benchmarked very fast on my larger datasets

Answer (score 1):

We could use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(word_set, ""))
```

---

Or make use of `table` with vectorized option

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(word_set, ""), word_set))[2:1])
#   values
#ind     a c d e g h i l n o p r s t u
#  clear 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
#  laugh 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
#  cigar 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
#  honda 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#  tulip 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1
#  asset 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0
```